# Is it possible that the dimension of the intersection of a nested sequence of Hilbert space is 1?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$

Let $\{h_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in H$ be a sequence of linearly independent vectors in $H$

Let 
$$
V=
\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty
\overline{
\operatorname{
span
}}
\{h_m\}_{m \geq n}
$$

Is it possible that
$$
\dim V=1
$$

Thanks

Comment: What is $V$ if $h_n=e_0+e_n$ for $n \geq 1$?

Comment: Ok @RamirodelaVega thanks , shame on me it was banal

Comment: No shame: easy-to-answer questions are the best! :)  Seriously, in some way easy-to-answer-by-experts are the best questions for non-experts to ask. I guess in a perfect world that would be what experts would be for. :)